# MySQL UPDATE records referenced by another table

Tags: mysql, join

I need to update a specific column of all records whose primary key is referenced by a specific column in another table.  (The foreign key relationship is already set up.)
An analog to what I'm trying to do would be this:

Table 1: Sandwiches

| Sandwich(varchar) [Primary Key] | Requested(bool) |
| --- | --- |
| Salami | 1 |
| Pastrami | Null |
| Ham | 0 |
| Turkey | 1 |

Table 2: Requests

| Character(varchar) | Sandwich (varchar) [Foreign Key to Sandwiches] |
| --- | --- |
| Charlie | Ham |
| Linus | Turkey |
| Marcy | Ham |
| Lucy | Salami |
| Snoopy | Pastrami |

I want every null value in sandwiches.requested updated to 1 if there is a record in requests referencing it's primary key.  E.g., since Pastrami has a null value for sandwiches.requested and Snoopy requested Pastrami, I want sandwiches.requested updated to 1  for Pastrami, so that Sandwiches looks thus:

Table 1: Sandwiches

| Sandwich(varchar) [Primary Key] | Requested(bool) |
| --- | --- |
| Salami | 1 |
| Pastrami | 1 |
| Ham | 0 |
| Turkey | 1 |

I know how to:

```
SELECT SANDWICHES.SANDWICH, SANDWICHES.REQUESTED FROM SANDWICHES INNER JOIN REQUESTS ON SANDWICHES.SANDWICH = REQUESTS.SANDWICH WHERE REQUESTED = NULL
```

which returns:

| Sandwich | Requested |
| --- | --- |
| Pastrami | Null |

telling me which ones I want to update, but say my data set were too large to manually perform all the updates.  How would I create an update command to update every match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update SANDWICHES JOIN REQUESTS ON SANDWICHES.SANDWICH = REQUESTS.SANDWICH set SANDWICHES.REQUESTED = 1 WHERE SANDWICHES.REQUESTED = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforwardly, just:

```
update Sandwiches
set Requested=1
where Sandwich in (select distinct Sandwich from Requests)
```